# How to remove divergence from any vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

I am trying to simulate fluids in 2D. I have a vector field which represents the flux; a continuous function that maps 2D positions to 2D velocity. I do some simulation steps and the flux changes. The new flux may have non-zero divergence, which is undesired, because I want to simulate non-compressible fluid. Therefore I want to have zero divergence at all points by changing the flux as little as possible. How can I calculate this most optimally and accurately?

My failed attempts:

- I found [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) which can be useful, but I don't think it tries to stay as close as possible to the original vector field with non-zero divergence.
- I could not get [this](https://www.karlsims.com/fluid-flow.html#:%7E:text=Removing%20divergence) to work. The formula there does not even make sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Some of us may be happy to help, but you should add more detail on your problem (pde, numerical method, etc)

Comment: @EditPiAf thanks for the suggestion. May I ask the specific details that you think are missing from the question? I am fine with using pde or numerical methods, whichever does the trick. I am also very interested in a pros-cons comparison if possible.

I am doing my own research on the side. If I run into more specific problems, I will update the question. I am merely trying to figure this problem out.

Comment: Please specify the equations governing the 2D motion of incompressible fluids, and the expression of the flux. You can enter equations using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Steady or time-dependent flow?

Comment: @RRL time-dependent, interactive, real-time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me has been [Hodge decomposition](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elowdanie/hodge_decomposition.pdf).

I have found exactly what I was looking for [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Real-Time-Fluid-Dynamics-for-Games-Stam/5127ac7b58e36ffd13ca4437fc123c6a018dc436?p2df). It even has an [example implementation](https://github.com/CFusion-zz/Real-Time-Fluid-Dynamics-for-Games).

In hindsight, I should have asked this question in [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). What I have been trying to achieve was similar to [plasma pong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGJO5bydch4).